# Is it possible to create a clone/wrapper of Context, having a different locale set for it than the original?

Tags: android, formatting, android-resources, android-locale

### Background

I'm trying to avoid wrong formatting issues on various usages of Context, so that numbers will be set like on English instead of Arabic and others.

### The problem

One simple example of a function that doesn't let me set the locale myself is [**formatShortFileSize**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter#formatShortFileSize(android.content.Context,%20long)), and just uses Context:

```
fun getHeapMemStats(context: Context): String {
    val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
    val maxMemInBytes = runtime.maxMemory()
    val availableMemInBytes = maxMemInBytes - (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory())
    val usedMemInBytes = maxMemInBytes - availableMemInBytes
    val usedMemInPercentage = usedMemInBytes * 100 / maxMemInBytes
    return "used: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, usedMemInBytes) + " / " +
            Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, maxMemInBytes) + " (" + usedMemInPercentage + "%)"
}
```

### What I've tried

At first I thought I should use a customized ContextWrapper, but it didn't seem like it could be useful.

Then I tried to use [**createConfigurationContext**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration)), and then copy the configuration and setting a locale for it:

```
Log.d("AppLog", "getHeapMemStats:${getHeapMemStats(this)}")
val newConfiguration=Configuration(resources.configuration)
newConfiguration.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
val newContext=  createConfigurationContext(newConfiguration)
Log.d("AppLog", "getHeapMemStats2:${getHeapMemStats(newContext)}")
Log.d("AppLog", "getHeapMemStats3:${getHeapMemStats(this)}")
```

This works only partially, as the "MB" is written fine, but not the actual digits:

```
getHeapMemStats:used: ٥٫٠ ميغابايت / ٢٦٨ ميغابايت (1%)
getHeapMemStats2:used: ٥٫٠ MB / ٢٦٨ MB (1%)
getHeapMemStats3:used: ٥٫١ ميغابايت / ٢٦٨ ميغابايت (1%)
```

### The question

How come only the units get localized according to what I've set, and not the digits?

How can I make the Context/resources to be set to a locale of my choice, that not just the words will be set according to it, but also the digits?